# Изменение значения переменной внутри функции через указатель

Tags: c, функции, указатели

**Код:**

```
 int main() 
{
    int param1 = 10;
    int param2 = 10;
    int res1 = ChangeValuesP(param1,param2);

    printf("[1] %d | %d | %d | \n", res1, param1, param2); 

    param1 = 10;
    param2 = 10;

    int res2 = ChangeValues(param1, param2);

}

int ChangeValuesP(int *param1, int *param2)
{
    int t1 = 15;
    int t2 = 15;
    param1 = &t1;
    param2 = &t2;
    return 3;
}

int ChangeValues(int param1, int param2)
{
    param1 = 100;
    param2 = 100;   
    return 300;
}
```

Вот что я хочу сделать:

Функции `ChangeValuesP` значения записываются через указатель, и как мне кажется (я прав?) они должны остаться после выполненя данной функции (т.е. значение 15 а не 10 как было до вызова)

В итоге во что получается:

```
[1] 3 | 10 | 10 | 
[2] 300 | 10 | 10 |
```

т.е. посе выполнения `ChangeValuesP` значения парамет ров вернулись в исходное.

**Как сделать так, чтобы значения параметров этих остались такими, какие им были присвоены в самой функции?**

Я где-то такое встречал, похоже на передачу параметров на ссылке.
Спасибо

P.S.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[1] 3 | 15 | 15 | 
[2] 300 | 10 | 10 |
```

Comment: Ошибка 2. `int res1 = ChangeValuesP(&param1,&param2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как сделать то, [что вы хотите](https://ideone.com/YVrbmJ):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ChangeValuesP(int *param1, int *param2)
{
    int t1 = 15;
    int t2 = 15;
    *param1 = t1;
    *param2 = t2;
    return 3;
}

int ChangeValues(int param1, int param2)
{
    param1 = 100;
    param2 = 100;
    return 300;
}

int main()
{
    int param1 = 10;
    int param2 = 10;
    int res1 = ChangeValuesP(&param1,&param2);

    printf("[1] %d | %d | %d | \n", res1, param1, param2);

    param1 = 10;
    param2 = 10;

    int res2 = ChangeValues(param1, param2);

    printf("[2] %d | %d | %d | \n", res2, param1, param2);

}
```

В С передачи по ссылке нет.
Вы должны передавать указатели, и работать со значениями через их разыменование.

Comment: Сапсибо большое! Получилось, буду дальше разбираться